# Can I use arrays to make multiple choice quiz?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm a beginner at C program.
As a teacher if you want to make a program to generate random Multiple Choice questions for your students to practice:
Can I use random function for arrays? To generate questions.
Can I use a 2nd array to give "a","b","c" answers referring to the question array?
Do I need to use some more advanced function or can it be done with if statements, for loops, arrays, and random function?

The code I inserted is far from correct or the way to program my Multiple Choice Quiz. However I hope it illustrates what I am trying to achieve with my C program.

Any help I would really appreciate. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void){

    int ans;
    int count;
    const char*string[]={"What's your name?","How old are you","Where are you from"};



    for (count=0; string[count]<2;count++){
        printf ("%s\n",rand(string[]));
        printf ("Answer : \n");
        scanf  ("%d\n");
        }


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `string[count]<2`? And `scanf  ("%d\n");` where are you going to store the value? **Do I need to use some more advanced function or can it be done with if statements, for loops, arrays, and random function?**, yes everything can be done with that. You are too lost for it to be possible to help you.

Comment: I was just trying to look for a way that the program can record how many questions were asked. I said <2 so it would ask 0,1 and 2. Finally I wanted to calculate the percentage answered correctly.